# how should I process a password before the cryptographic algorithm is used?

Tags: passwords

Before I use cryptography algorithm or whatever one i choose, how should I attach the salt to the password string? I was thinking I could put alternate characters from the password and salt into the string for hashing before i get to the end of the password string then tack the rest of the salt on or something like this? also what cryptographic algorithm would you recommend if i want to minimize the ease with which someone can get the password from the hash?

Comment: Most implementations of appropriate hash algorithms (BCrypt, SCrypt, PBKDF2) will take care of the salt themself, so you can just use them without worrying about the generation of the salt.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a cryptographic hash for password storage.

Use a slow, secure, tried and tested algorithm.

For example:

- Bcrypt (the hashing algorithm, not the encryption one).
- PBKDF2
- Scrypt